# Finding points of intersection for higher degree polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I was just wondering if it is possible to algebraically solve a pair of equation for their points of intersection.
For example: I am given the two equations $ f(x)= 2.551 \times 10^{-7}(x)^2(x-30)^2(x-55)^2$ and $g(x)= 2.5\times 10^{-6}(x)^2(x-25)^2(x-50)^2$ and told to determine where $g(x)$ is above $f(x)$, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Those are not equations. Assuming you meant functions, you would solve $g(x) \ge f(x)$ the same way you would solve $p(x) \ge 0$ for a single polynomial (in this case $p = g - f$). It's not clear what you mean by "algebraically" since you can't generally find polynomial roots in a closed form.

Comment: I set g(x) => f(x) and, when simplified to equal 0) have come up with the function h(x)= -5.935x^6+888.837x^5-48108.896x^4-1143418.487x^3-9196232.331x^2+6.8        do I now just factor and use a sign analysis chart to find where g(x)>f(x)?

Comment: That was the hint. Finding $p(x) \ge 0$ for one polynomial is equivalent to finding $g(x) \ge f(x)$ for two polynomials. So if your question, in the simplest terms, is "*can roots of arbitrary degree polynomials be found algebraically*", then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

This question amounts to finding the roots of the difference of the two functions, $g(x)-f(x)$. Unfortunately, it won't be possible to find those roots in general if the polynomial is of any degree greater than four. You could still approximate the roots with something like Newton's method or just graph the functions to find an answer good enough for practical purposes.